# right left shift bits in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I did a small test on bit shifting in C, and all of the shifts by 0, 8, 16 bits are OK and I understood what's happening.

But the 32 bits right or left shift which is not clear to me, the variable I'm doing the test with is 32-bit long.

Then, I changed the 32-bit variables which would hold the shifting results, but 32-bit right left shifts are the same!

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main() {
    uint32_t code = 0xCDBAFFEE;

    uint64_t bit32R = code >> 32;
    uint16_t bit16R = code >> 16;
    uint8_t bit8R = code >> 8;
    uint8_t bit0R = code >> 0;

    uint64_t bit32L = code << 32;
    uint16_t bit16L = code << 16;
    uint8_t bit8L = code << 8;
    uint8_t bit0L = code << 0;

    printf("Right shift:\nbit32R %.16x\nbit16R %x\nbit8R %x\nbit0R %x\n\n",
           bit32R, bit16R, bit8R, bit0R);
    printf("Left shift:\nbit32L %.16x\nbit16L %x\nbit8L %x\nbit0L %x\n\n",
           bit32L, bit16L, bit8L, bit0L);
}
```

Here's the result I get:

```
Right shift:
bit32R 00000000cdbaffee
bit16R 0
bit8R cdba
bit0R ff

Left shift:
bit32L 00000000cdbaffee
bit16L 0
bit8L 0
bit0L 0

Process returned 61 (0x3D)   execution time : 0.041 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behaviour. A shift value of `32` is too large for a 32 bit `int` (same for 16 bit if your platform has 16 bit `int`). And use the `PRInX` macros from `inttypes.h` to print fixed-width types. You have a missconception how  integer operations work.

Comment: I changed the include file to stdint! Which didn't change anything, but I forgot about stdint, and included inttypes. But I think they are the same, at least for my code.

Comment: Maybebe before making assumptions, it is a good idea to read what the headers provide, how they are related and what `PRInX` means?

Comment: Could you tell me in brief what inttypes and stdint offer?

Comment: Is google down?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right shifting an integer by a number of bits equal or greater than its size is undefined behavior.

> **C11 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators**
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> shift-expression: additive-expression
>     shift-expression << additive-expression
>     shift-expression >> additive-expression
> ```
>
> Constraints
>
> Each of the operands shall have integer type.
>
> Semantics
>
> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.
>
> The result of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If `E1` has an unsigned type, the value of the result is `E1` × 2<sup>E2</sup>, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If `E1` has a signed type and nonnegative value, and `E1` × 2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
>
> The result of `E1 >> E2` is `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions. If `E1` has an unsigned type or if E1 has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of `E1` / 2<sup>E2</sup>. If `E1` has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined.

The size of `int` on your platform seems to be at most 32 bits, so the initializers for `bit32R` and `bit32L` have undefined behavior.

The 64-bit expressions should be written:

```
uint64_t bit32R = (uint64_t)code >> 32;
```

and

```
uint64_t bit32L = (uint64_t)code << 32;
```

Furthermore, the formats used in `printf` are not correct for the arguments passed (unless `int` has 64 bits, which would produce different output).

Your compiler does not seem to be fully C99 compliant, you should add a final `return 0;` statement at the end of the body of function `main()`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) {
    uint32_t code = 0xCDBAFFEE;

    uint64_t bit32R = (uint64_t)code >> 32;
    uint16_t bit16R = code >> 16;
    uint8_t bit8R = code >> 8;
    uint8_t bit0R = code >> 0;

    uint64_t bit32L = (uint64_t)code << 32;
    uint16_t bit16L = code << 16;
    uint8_t bit8L = code << 8;
    uint8_t bit0L = code << 0;

    printf("Right shift:\n"
           "bit32R %.16"PRIx64"\n"
           "bit16R %"PRIx16"\n"
           "bit8R %"PRIx8"\n"
           "bit0R %"PRIx8"\n\n",
           bit32R, bit16R, bit8R, bit0R);

    printf("Left shift:\n"
           "bit32L %.16"PRIx64"\n"
           "bit16L %"PRIx16"\n"
           "bit8L %"PRIx8"\n"
           "bit0L %"PRIx8"\n\n",
           bit32L, bit16L, bit8L, bit0L);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Right shift:
bit32R 0000000000000000
bit16R cdba
bit8R ff
bit0R ee

Left shift:
bit32L cdbaffee00000000
bit16L 0
bit8L 0
bit0L ee
```

this might not be what you expect, because the types of the variables are somewhat inconsistent.

Comment: return 0 for main() in C99 never was mandatory, it is said that if omitted return value of 0 would be expected provided by compiler (prototype of main() fuction is also platform dependent, void main(void)  also acceptable). Tbh there very few fully C99-compliant  compilers and even less C++11 ones at the moment, especially on embedded platforms. I  wasn't even sure that he got access to PRIx macros, compiler I had at hand didn't had them in header

Comment: @Swift: the status printed by the running environment `Process returned 61 (0x3D)` indicates the compiler did **not** add the implicit `return 0;` mandated by C99, hence my statement about the non-compliant compiler.  I wouldn't be surprised if this environment is based on MSVC. In any case, it is good style to always return 0 (or some meaningful exit status) explicitly at the end of `main()`.  The C99 implicit return semantics is a lame fix for sloppy code IMHO.

Comment: Absolutely! That worked just perfectly. But why the (%.16x) didn't work for the 64 variable size? It shows the 64-bit hex size but the shifting is not correct. And with PRIx64, is working fine?

Comment: @PerchEagle: `"%.16"PRIx64` expects a value of type `uint64_t` and prints the hexadecimal conversion with at least 16 digits. If you use `%.16x`, you also get 16 hex digits (8 of which are necessarily `0`), but the expected type is `unsigned int` which is probably incompatible with `uint64_t`, hence your `printf` format has undefined behavior. If type `unsigned long long` has 64 bits, `PRIx16` could expand to `"llu"`.

Comment: But I get the same output without the type casting!

Comment: I applied unsigned long long, but it's the same result! Another interesting effect is the I don't get 64-bit shift. Maximum I can is 32 where I can see a change in the output.

Comment: @PerchEagle: actually, the maximum shift value for `uint64_t` in either direction is 63. `unsigned long long` is guaranteed to have at least 64 bits, so you can indeed write `unsigned long long bit32R = (unsigned long long)code >> 32;` and use `%.16llx` as a `printf` format.

Comment: @PerchEagle: regarding *But I get the same output without the type casting!*: I am not sure which type casting you are referring to, but *undefined behavior* includes *expected behavior*, it can happen by chance but it is not guaranteed.

Comment: MSVC actually was doing that since very old version. @PerchEagle the possibility (very bad one) why you could get proper result that  compiler _actually_ generated 64-bit instruction, which corrupted a  32-bit word before one that was assigned to variable (hence, if you use address of that variable printf directly, you'll get proper result, which gets lost after assignment). VC6 or turboc were known to do such things, which were making UB  very dangerous.

Comment: @Swift: on 64-bit intel linux systems, the first few `printf` arguments are passed in registers, which would partly explain the observed behavior.

Comment: @chqrlie Ah, that calling convention.. now I'm curious how they did implement va_list then

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you are using `%x` to print a 64-bit integer. You should use the correct format specifier for each variable. There are macros for this available:

```
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#include <inttypes.h>

// ...

printf("64 bit result: %" PRIx64 "\n", bit32R);
printf("16 bit result: %" PRIx16 "\n", bit16R);
printf("8 bit result: %" PRIx8 "\n", bit8R);
```

More information can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cinttypes/).

Comment: While `%x` is wrong, using PRIx64 doesn't change the result of the shift.

Comment: If PRIx64 doesn't change the result, then why %x is wrong? I get the same results with your modification. I even can get the hex full format of 64-bit with %.16x modifier.

Comment: @Perch these are platform-specific things. In general, it appears to work, but then either fails on other platforms, or fails when you write more advanced code. I'll admit that I don't bother to use all these macros when I'm writing code, but you should only skip them if you always know what platform you will be running on. Otherwise, disaster will occur.

Comment: I appreciate your hint, but anyway how do I suppose to know such macros when I want to write a code? Like this one "#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS"? Which I think is related to inttypes.h.

Comment: @PerchEagle: The same way you are supposed to know to use `uint64_t` for 64-bit integers. But I understand that it is easy to see `int*_t` being used in some code, and to copy it, and that way it is hard to discover that you need the `PRI*` macros when trying to print them. It would be nice if the macros were mentioned in the manpage of `printf()`...

Comment: @PerchEagle %x is (most likely) wrong, because %x is meant for int arguments. But since you use uint64_t, which is either an `unsigned long` or even `unsigned long long` type, you must use `%lx`, `%llx` or PRIx64. This is why %x is wrong. With my comment, I wanted to point out, that using the correct format specifier, fixes the output, *but it does not fix the previous calculation*.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing 64 bit left shift there, because  code is uint32_t, so compiler uses 32bit version of operator. Also, you should tell print  to use long long (same as uint64_t)

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
uint32_t code = 0xCDBAFFEE;


uint64_t bit32R=((uint64_t)code)>>32;
uint16_t bit16R=code>>16;
uint8_t bit8R=code>>8;
uint8_t bit0R=code>>0;

uint64_t bit32L=((uint64_t)code)<<32;
uint16_t bit16L=code<<16;
uint8_t bit8L=code<<8;
uint8_t bit0L=code<<0;


printf("Right shift:\nbit32R %llx\nbit16R %x\nbit8R %x\nbit0R %x\n\n", bit32R,bit16R,bit8R,bit0R);
printf("Leftt shift:\nbit32L %llx\nbit16L %x\nbit8L %x\nbit0L %x", bit32L,bit16L,bit8L,bit0L);
}
```

Result is:

```
Right shift:
bit32R 0
bit16R cdba
bit8R ff
bit0R ee

Leftt shift:
bit32L cdbaffee00000000
bit16L 0
bit8L 0
bit0L ee
```

You should use the macros defined in inttypes.h if you have C99 compliant compiler, sadly some platforms do not have those definitions. Format descriptors for printf are platform-dependent.

Comment: OP doesn't claim to do 64 bit. Also 64 bit isn't `long long` on all platforms.

Comment: @Olaf Dietsche : that pretty much was the claim. uint64_t bit32L=code<<32; is same as uint32_t bit32L=code<<32. But I agree, though based on reaction of his printf output, _his_ platform  got  64bit as long long.

Comment: But there is uint64_t which gives you 64-bit variable.

Comment: @PerchEagle Yes, you get a 64 bit result, but only after producing undefined behaviour. If you want a reliable/defined 64 bit result, you must use 64 bit arguments for the calculation too. This is why Swift suggested a cast.